# Selenium - web scraping multiple urls for same contents but slightly different xpaths

Tags: python, html, loops, selenium, xpath

I am using Selenium to **scrape** multiple urls for the same tables, but the xpath for those tables are slightly different.

Below are my codings:

```
my_urls = ["https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/own-disp?action=getowner&CIK=0001548760",
"https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/own-disp?action=getowner&CIK=0001366010",
"https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/own-disp?action=getowner&CIK=0001164390"]

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
for url in my_urls:
    driver.get(url)    
    export_table=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('')[0]
    export_table.text
```

xpath1:`/html/body/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody`

xpath2:`/html/body/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody`

How can I use one xpath to extract the contents from those urls? And export all results to a dictionary?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Will one xpath work with a specific url and not the other? If so you should just use the `try:...except:...finally` expression on each xpath

Comment: try this xpath - //tbody/tr[2]/td//td/table/tbody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if you want to get the text from each xpath. If you wanted to have one path for each url then you should use a dictionary to have a map between url and xpath. You can iterate over that dictionary to do what you want to do.

```py
import json
from selenium import webdriver
my_urls = ["https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/own-disp?action=getowner&CIK=0001548760",
"https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/own-disp?action=getowner&CIK=0001366010",
"https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/own-disp?action=getowner&CIK=0001164390"]

xpath1 = """/html/body/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody"""
xpath2 = """/html/body/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody"""

def getpath(element):
    try:
        return element[0].text
    except IndexError as _:
        return None

export_table = {}

driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe")
for url in my_urls:
    driver.get(url)
    export_table[url] = {path: getpath(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(path)) for path in [xpath1, xpath2]}

driver.close()

json.dumps(export_table)
```

Output

```
{
  "https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/own-disp?action=getowner&CIK=0001548760": {
    "/html/body/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody": "Issuer Filings Transaction Date Type of Owner\\nFacebook Inc 0001326801 2019-04-26 director, 10 percent owner, officer: COB and CEO",
    "/html/body/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody": "Mailing Address\\nC/O FACEBOOK, INC.\\n1601 WILLOW ROAD\\nMENLO PARK CA 94025"
  },
  "https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/own-disp?action=getowner&CIK=0001366010": {
    "/html/body/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody": "Issuer Filings Transaction Date Type of Owner\\nFacebook Inc 0001326801 2019-07-08 director, officer: Chief Operating Officer\\nSVMK Inc. 0001739936 2019-02-21 director\\nWALT DISNEY CO/\\nCurrent Name:TWDC Enterprises 18 Corp. 0001001039 2017-11-22 director\\nSTARBUCKS CORP 0000829224 2011-11-14 director\\neHealth, Inc. 0001333493 2008-06-10 director",
    "/html/body/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody": "Mailing Address\\n1 FACEBOOK WAY\\nMENLO PARK CA 94025"
  },
  "https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/own-disp?action=getowner&CIK=0001164390": {
    "/html/body/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody": null,
    "/html/body/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody": "Issuer Filings Transaction Date Type of Owner\\nACE LTD\\nCurrent Name:Chubb Ltd 0000896159 2019-06-06 officer: Executive Vice President*"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Glad to learn from creating a function and do the work!